# How to display two types of user account pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a user model with the following fields: first_name, last_name, email.

The client wants two pages. The first page to edit the first and last name and a second page to edit the email address.

One option I thought about, is using params to determine what partial should be rendered in **user/edit**:

```
  <% if !params[:section] %>
    <%= render :partial => 'form_for_name' %>
  <% elsif params[:section] == 'email' %>
    <%= render :partial => 'form_for_email' %>
  <% end %>
```

The url for the first page would look like: http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit

and the second page: http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit?section=email

One thing to note. The user model contains the following code in **def update**:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

This means, on the email page, if user puts an invalid email, the error is displayed on the first page instead of the email page.

I am looking to see what is the best way to implement this scenario. Or should I have 2 controllers (name and email), which inherit from the user controller? Each controller with their respective views.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you send the "section" parameter to the update call also? This way when there is an error, and goes to the edit page, the section parameter will be available and the correct form will be rendered.

The way to send "section" during the update should be quite simple too. Post the bit where you have your form and i'll show you how to pass the current "section" to the update action. Basically you just spell out the path "user_path(@user,:section => params[:section])" in the form action.

Comment: HI aditya, you mean this bit? <%= form_for(@user, :url => user_path(@user), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

Comment: yup, use <%= form_for(@user, :url => user_path(@user,:section => params[:section]), :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

Comment: Thanks for getting back Aditya. By this, I assume, the way I am doing this (i.e. via params) is a good approach?

Comment: Sure, it's fine. Don't go into multiple controllers absolutely or subclassing the controller. If you want to make it cleaner check out railscast on multi-step forms. http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms